# Does High-Ram in Google Colab refer to GPU RAM or CPU RAM?

Tags: gpu, google-colaboratory

I see that you get better GPUs with the Pro account. But does switching to High-Ram affect the GPU's memory or the CPU's memory? I don't see it spelled out exactly anywhere, and maybe this is just common knowledge among ML experts.